# How to hook into the CPT's title placeholder?

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks, title

I want to change the default **placeholder text** in my Custom Post Type title field. This isn't possible while registering a new post type.

The following screenshot describes it.

[image: Screen from WP Admin]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use a code which differs from yours a little bit. There is no need to get the current screen using the `enter_title_here`-filter because you have already a post-object:

```
/**
 * Filter: Modifies the standard placeholder text
 * @param string $title
 * @param WP_Post $post
 * @return string
 */
function my_enter_title_here( $title, $post ) {
    if ( 'POST_TYPE' == $post->post_type ) {
        $title = 'Custom placeholder text here';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'enter_title_here', 'my_enter_title_here', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function change_default_title( $title ) {
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    // you can copy/paste the following if statement for other post types
    if( 'POST_TYPE' == $screen->post_type ) {
      $title = 'Custom placeholder text here';
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'enter_title_here', 'change_default_title' );
```

Comment: Please don't dump code as an answer. As a longstanding member you should know that. Please file an [edit] and add an explanation to how your code works and how it should be used. Thank you.